# CSS transform rotate and translate position error

Tags: css

I might be missing something, but this CSS code:

```
width: 150px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 40px;
```

... should produce the same result as this one:

```
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
transform: 
  translate(20px, 40px)
  rotate(90deg);
```

In my machine (chrome windows) they do not appear in the same position.
Check the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/venih/1/edit)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If they should not produce the same result, why would they be in the same position?

Comment: They should produce the same but they don't. got it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue lies with your transform translation.

You set the transform origin to 50% 50%, the center of `.rotated`.
So I'll be using the center of each box as its origin.

The origin of `.target` is at 115px X 120px:

```
X1: (150px width / 2) + 40px left = 115px
Y1: (200px height / 2) + 20px top = 120px
```

The original origin (before transform) of `.rotated` is at 100px x 75px:

```
X2: (200px width / 2) + 0px left = 100px
Y2: (150px height / 2) + 0px top = 75px
```

To align both origins, you'll need move `.rotated` by 15px X and 45px Y:

```
ΔX: X1 - X2 = 115px - 100px = 15px
ΔY: Y1 - Y2 = 120px - 75px = 45px
```

So, to align the two boxes, your transform definition would be:

```
transform: 
    translate(15px, 45px)
    rotate(90deg);
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/macizuxu/1/edit).
I added a "hover" animation to illustrate the transform.

Comment: This answer is so good that makes me wish there were a bonus reward button! Gratz showdev.